# yum + unpacking of archive failed

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, repository

during hive installation we get the following errors

```
 /usr/bin/yum  install hive_2_6_0_3_8

 Installing : hive_2_6_0_3_8-1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8.noarch                                                                                                              
1/1
Error unpacking rpm package hive_2_6_0_3_8-1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf: 
cpio: rename
 Verifying  : hive_2_6_0_3_8-1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8.noarch                                                                                                              
1/1

Failed:
hive_2_6_0_3_8.noarch 0:1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8

Complete!
```

what exactly the problem here?

```
ls -ltd  /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 24 Nov 26 14:16 /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf


ls -ltr  /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 hive hadoop 6 Nov 26 14:16 conf.server

rpm -qa | grep  hive | grep 1000
hive_2_6_0_3_8-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8.noarch
```

Comment: `/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf` is a directory, not a file.

Comment: so how to know what is the file , or maybe I wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In package hive_2_6_0_3_8-1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8.noarch the `/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf` is regular file. While on your system it is a directory. Cpio (and therefore rpm) cannot convert directory to file (and vice versa). Just remove (or move away) the directory `/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In the package `hive_2_6_0_3_8-1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8.noarch` the `/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf` is regular file.

Whereas on your system it is a directory.

`Cpio` (and therefore `rpm`) cannot convert a directory to a file (and vice versa).

Just `rm` (or `mv`) the directory `/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hive/conf` to another location and try again.

That worked for me.